# How to detect expired password using Python Fabric?

Tags: python, ssh, fabric

Using the following code, I'm unable to get Fabric to detect an expired password prompt at login.  The session doesn't timeout, and the abort_on_prompts parameter doesn't appear to be triggering.  How I can configure Fabric to detect this state?

```
from fabric.api import env, run, execute
from fabric import network
from fabric.context_managers import settings

def host_type():
    with settings(abort_on_prompts=True):
        print ("Using abort mode %(abort_on_prompts)s" % env)
        result = run('uname -s')
return result

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print ("Fabric v%(version)s" % env)
    env.user = 'myuser'
    env.password = 'user67user'
    env.hosts = ['10.254.254.143']
    host_types = execute(host_type)
```

Executing this script results in a hung script, as depicted below:

```
    Fabric v1.11.1.post1
    [10.254.254.143] Executing task 'host_type'
    Using abort mode True
    [10.254.254.143] run: uname -s
    [10.254.254.143] out: WARNING: Your password has expired.
    [10.254.254.143] out: You must change your password now and login again!
    [10.254.254.143] out: Changing password for myuser.
    [10.254.254.143] out: (current) UNIX password:
```

Answer (score 0):

Fabric include a way to answer prompts questions.

You can use [`prompts`](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.9/usage/env.html#prompts) dictionary on the [`with settings`](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.9/api/core/context_managers.html#fabric.context_managers.settings). In the dictionary every key is the question in standard output you want to answer, and the value is your answer.

So in your example:

```
from fabric.api import env, run, execute
from fabric import network
from fabric.context_managers import settings

def host_type():
    with settings(prompts={"(current) UNIX password": "new_password"}):
        result = run('uname -s')
return result

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print ("Fabric v%(version)s" % env)
    env.user = 'myuser'
    env.password = 'user67user'
    env.hosts = ['10.254.254.143']
    host_types = execute(host_type)
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a good start in the right direction.  I subsequently learned about prompts for another task I was building for changing the password.  FYI, that example won't work as is on at 2 Linux variants I've tested against.  The Fabric code uses an _endwith function for matching, so you need to include a trailing space, such as "UNIX password: "  

Since I won't know the new password and definitely don't want to accidentally set one, I'm using the prompts to send a bad password, which causes the operation to fail with an exit code of 10.

Comment: Continued:

    `with settings(prompts={'UNIX password: ': 'BOGUS'}):
        host_types = execute(host_type)`